# C++ resizing issue

Tags: c++, winapi

I have successfully opened a win32 window(without OpenGL context). Opening the window, then resizing it causes a lot of issues. How do we properly handle resizing inside the win32 api? I create a window with WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW and making the window resizable. Mainly, I attempt to handle the resizing with the WM_SIZE event handler.

[image: Image of C++ issue resizing]

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <Windows.h>
#include <gl/GL.h>
#include <gl/GLU.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
HINSTANCE hInstanceGlobal;
LRESULT CALLBACK wndproc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    switch (message) {
    default:
        return DefWindowProcA(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    case WM_PAINT:
        BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        return 0;

    case WM_SIZE:
        SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
        PostMessage(hWnd, WM_PAINT, 0, 0);
        return 0;
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        
        break;
    case WM_SETCURSOR:
        if (LOWORD(lParam) == HTCLIENT) {
            SetCursor(LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW));
            return TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }

    return DefWindowProcA(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    
}
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
    int       nShowCmd) {

#ifdef _DEBUG
    AllocConsole();
    //SetWindowPos(GetConsoleWindow(), 0, 1920, 200, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);
    AttachConsole(GetCurrentProcessId());
    freopen("CON", "w", stdout);
    
#endif  
    hInstanceGlobal = hInstance;
    const char* CLASSNAME = "APIOPENGL";
    WNDCLASS cl = { };
    cl.lpfnWndProc = wndproc;
    cl.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    cl.hInstance = hInstance;
    cl.lpszClassName = CLASSNAME;
    
    RegisterClass(&cl);

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_APPWINDOW|WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        CLASSNAME,
        "Opengl Window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW |WS_CLIPCHILDREN|WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
    );
    if (hWnd == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nShowCmd);

    MSG msg;
    MessageBox(NULL, (char*)GetLastError(), "Hello", NULL);
    bool bRet;
    while ((bRet = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) != 0) {
        
        if (GetKeyState(VK_RMENU) & 0x8000)
        {
            cout << "Pressed" << endl;
        }
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: for what you call `SetWindowPos` on `WM_SIZE` ? this is mistake. and not need `WM_PAINT` post. call `InvalidateRect` instead. but usually we need handle `WM_SIZE` if we need move child windows (we are "frame")or recreate bitmaps, etc.. in your case you not need handle `WM_SIZE` at all. comment your `case WM_SIZE:` and see

Comment: You can find many sample of the web: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/samples/. Win32 API is low level so starting either with a book or a sample will give you a huge start. **You should also be able to find samples specific for OpenGL that already have the basic...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in the screenshot (black background) is because you have not set the `hbrBackground` member of the window class. According to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-wndclassa):

> When this member is **NULL**, an application must paint its own
> background whenever it is requested to paint in its client area. To
> determine whether the background must be painted, an application can
> either process the [`WM_ERASEBKGND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-erasebkgnd) message or test the **fErase**
> member of the [`PAINTSTRUCT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-paintstruct) structure filled by the
> [`BeginPaint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-beginpaint) function.

Like the answer of @Stra, use `FillRect` to fill the background.

Or initialize `hbrBackground`:

```
hInstanceGlobal = hInstance;
const char CLASSNAME[] = "APIOPENGL";
WNDCLASS cl = { };
cl.lpfnWndProc = wndproc;
cl.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
cl.hInstance = hInstance;
cl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
cl.lpszClassName = CLASSNAME;

RegisterClass(&cl);
```

Then you don’t need to process the `WM_SIZE` message.

In addition, you don’t need to call `GetKeyState` to get the `VK_RMENU` key Presse event, just process the `WM_SYSKEYDOWN` message and Indicates whether the key is an extended key:

```
/*case WM_SIZE:
    SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
    PostMessage(hWnd, WM_PAINT, 0, 0);
    return 0;*/
case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
    if (VK_MENU == wParam)
    {
        BOOL bit = (lParam >> 24) & 1;
        if (bit)
            cout << "Pressed" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: Hi, @dudewritecodde, Does this answer your question? Please feel free to contact me if you have any issue and if this really helps you, please also feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: [Resize window with Win32 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147766/resizing-window-with-win32-api)

In your WM_PAINT handler, it's possible that your getting that strange result because you aren't calling the FillRect function.

```
    case WM_PAINT:
       PAINTSTRUCT ps;
       HDC hdc = BeginPaint(m_hwnd, &ps);
       FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 6));
       EndPaint(m_hwnd, &ps);
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could let us know how you would properly resize a window and update the content inside the window.

Comment: @dudewritecodde This is Windows 101. Windows has been around for 30 years and these basic techniques haven't changed. I suggest you consult one of the many many many books on the subject.